# Bored or a bored person

Tags: adjectives, syntax, past-participles, semantics, morphology

> a. He is bored.

> b. He is a bored person.

Is it correct to use a noun with past participle when used an adjective? For example, The tired singer is not singing a new song. How to use past participle correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a. He is bored.  b. He is a bored person.

(a) and (b) are different.  *He is bored* describes the person at that point.  The phrase *bored person*, however, describes the person, one with the feeling of boredom already ingrained in his
life.

For the singer example, I would prefer

> The singer is tired and is not singing another song.

Nevertheless, there is nothing grammatically wrong with using a past participle as an adjective.

Comment: Nevertheless, there is nothing grammatically wrong with using a past participle as an adjective. _The tired mother cradled her new-born baby, while the delighted father sat by the bed._ But we wouldn't say _he is a bored person_, because _he is bored_ gets the meaning across more simply.

Comment: Thx, @Kate Bunting.  I have added a line.